# How to join one-to-many tables?

Tags: sqlite, join, android-sqlite

I have a scenario like below in SQLite:
Some items which their prices during time is stored inside price table. Current prices for an item is the one which:

1. Its Price.fkItemID == Item.id
2. It is the most recent match (has the maximum ID among those who match in criteria 1)

So how can I join below tables in SQLite such that I get a list of items with their current prices?

Besides, having several joins, will it cause too much performance degrade?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the row with the largest ID, use a correlated subquery which orders by the ID, and take just the first returned row:

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT price
        FROM Table2
        WHERE fkItemID = Table1.id
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS current_price
FROM Table1
```

This query is efficient if there is an index that allows searching on `fkItemID` and then sorting on `id`:

```
CREATE INDEX Table2_fkItemID_id ON Table2(fkItemID, id);
```

(If there aren't many historical prices, it is not really necessary to index the `id` column.)

Comment: Thanks for your query. Meanwhile I did handle the case another way. I added another field to table1 called CurrentPrice which must be updated manually whenever a new price is defined and the price item is also added to price table for historic reference. this way I should care the CurrentPrice value myself but it avoids a join query among two tables.

Comment: Do you know a query builder for SQLite?

Comment: This is a different question, and off-topic on Stack Overflow.